# Cant Ask For Two Integers At The Same Time

Tags: c

I am beginner at C. I am trying to practice some easy codes but I can't ask for two integers using `scanf`. When I try to build and run the code, it asks for `a` and I enter it as 2, then it asks for `b` and I enter it as 3. In the end, it prints `a` correctly but it doesn't print `b` correctly. It prints `b` as zero.
Here is my code :

```
int main()
{
    int a;
    int b;
    char c;
    printf("a icin bir deger giriniz. \n");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("b icin bir deger giriniz. \n");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    printf("c icin bir karakter tanimlaniyiniz. \n");
    scanf("%s",&c);
    printf("a'nin tanimlanmis degeri %d'dir. \n",a);
    printf("b'nin tanimlanmis degeri %d'dir. \n",b);
    printf("c'ye atanan karakter %c'dir. \n",c);
}
```

Comment: Is asking two integers really the problem? Try changing dangerous `scanf("%s",&c);` to `c = '@';`.

Comment: Why is it dangerous?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format `%s` is to read *strings*. For a string you need an *array* of characters, at least as large as the input *plus one* (for the special string null-terminator character).

To read a single character you should use `%c`, just like you do for `printf`. ***But*** remember that the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key from the last input will be added to the input buffer parsed by `scanf` as a newline. To skip this newline add a leading space in the formatting string:

```
scanf(" %c",&c);  // Read a single character, note the leading space
```